# Long running script causes 500 error. Only unrelated warnings, in log

Tags: php

Here's my file

```
$start = time();    
//sleep(32);//works
//sleep(33);//works
//sleep(36);//500 
sleep(46);//500   

echo(time() - $start);
```

Once I get to about 36 seconds, it is more likely that the page will 500 error, but it might run its course, without error.  Above 36 or so, and it will 500 every time.  But, I just got one to go 44 seconds.  So, you see, it's hard to pin down.  It definately will go 33 seconds and anyway, I had the host mod php.ini to script execution: 3600.  Windows server.

There are no errors, being generated, in the log.

Comment: Try `set_time_limit( 0 )` before sleeping.

Comment: browser or cli script?

Comment: Running the page in broswer

Comment: @Xorifelse, no change (I didnt expect there to be one, as the host has set this to 3600, in php.ini)

Comment: @DougCassidy Well, you didn't say you restarted the server ;) Anyways, while I am currently out of idea's how to solve your current issue... Check your `php.ini` and I think the resolution of your "error" is to comment out `;` the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll` as you don't have it installed. It's just a driver that does not exist, PDO is able to communicate with others such as `php_pdo_mysql`, which presumably works as a charm. You wouldn't notice unless you used `new PDO('sqlsrv:{etc..}')`

Comment: Tested,with phpinfo, my in-script commands: set_time_limit( 3777 ) are working.  but this has no effect on my problem, still 500 errors.

Comment: Note: I deleted all that BS about pdo, it was unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this turned out to be iis timing out, not php.

iis manager > fastcgi settings > process model > activity timeout
is where you set that.  After I raised the limit, from 30 seconds, my script worked fine.